# ASP.NET MVC Razor: Forma de optimizar for loop para evitar System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, loops

Buen día, básicamente mi pregunta es esa: tengo un aplicativo en mvc razor que carga un data context con varias tablas y vistas. Una vez cargados todos los models (en mi viewmodel) armo grillas usando for loops de la siguiente manera:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Grilla.Count; i++)
{
<tr id="@Model.Grilla[i].campo1">
   <td>
     @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Grilla[i].campo1)
   </td>
   <td>
     @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Grilla[i].campo2)
   </td>
</tr>

}
```

...
4 grillas mas

El problema lo tengo al ejecutar, al ser mucha cantidad de registros (400 por grilla) y muchas grillas (aprox 6) y generarse todas al mismo tiempo, me explota la memoria del Visual Studio 2015, mostrandome el siguiente error:

> Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Lo particular de este error es que solo se presenta cuando quiero depurar desde Visual Studio, si realizo la publicacion del sitio web y lo ejecuto, se ejecuta sin mayores problemas (aunque se demora unos 20-30 segundos en arrancar).

Mi  pregunta es la siguiente:

-Existe una forma de evitar que se llamen los for loops al mismo tiempo? (como usando un flag o llamandose entre si al terminar cada uno, o ponerles un numero de ejecucion)

-Existe alguna forma de ponerle un "index" al for loop para que sea mas rapido el manejo de datos?

-Existe una forma mas rapida que usar for loop?

-Alguna forma de ejecutar los for loop desde JQuery/Javascript para evitar que la pagina los cargue al mismo tiempo? (sin tener que reescribir todo el codigo de las grilla en javascript)

Gracias!!

Comment: publica tu controlador mi estimado :D

Comment: Hola, no es el controlador, lo estoy depurando y el problema se genera cuando el viewmodel recibe todo el modelo en adelante. Y probe dejando las grillas en i<1 y dejo de darme el error, ademas de acelerarse mucho la ejecucion, asi que el problema surge ahi. Saludos.

Comment: Los errores del tipo `System.OutOfMemoryException` se generan en el backend, un error en el frontend sería que el navegador se congele por efecto de la cantidad de contenido en el grid

Comment: Cual es el valor de `Model.Grilla.Count` ?

Comment: Daba 1500 registros, pero hay que tener en consideracion que estoy levantando como 6 grillas ademas de esa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ante todo muchas gracias por la ayuda. Ya encontré el error: básicamente se producía por el exceso de grillas que cargaba en mi pagina html. Este error no se generaba en el model, tampoco en el controller, solo se generaba en el View cuando cargaba todos los datos. Entiendo que este problema se producia en mi compilador y no en el navegador web por que el compilador incorpora de forma invisible varios puntos de control x cada renglon, duplicando su tamaño que de por si era considerable.

Ademas tenia mi vista duplicada en el layout, eso hizo que explotara la memoria. Lo resolvi quitando la vista duplicada (corrigiendo la codificacion que la duplicaba).

Comment: sería de mayor utilidad que coloques el código completo de la vista de antes (en la pregunta) y de cómo lo resolviste :D

Comment: Es que es demasiado codigo, justamente por eso dio ese error. son como 8000 lineas de codigo que se duplicaban + los puntos de control del visual studio.